# Sepia filter CS50 week 4

Tags: c, rgb, cs50

I need to create a filter that converts an colour image into sepia filter with the formulas below on my code. This is a CS50 week 4 problem set.

I am having trouble understanding the errors on I get when I run check50. Please see below my code and the errors that I got. The code makes sense and returns the expected rgb values but I still get two errors on check50.

```
:) sepia correctly filters single pixel 

:) sepia correctly filters simple 3x3 image 

:( sepia correctly filters more complex 3x3 image
    expected "25 22 17\n66 5...", not "25 22 17\n66 5..." - ERROR HERE
 
:( sepia correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "25 22 17\n66 5...", not "25 22 17\n66 5..." - ERROR HERE
```

`// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    float sr = 0;
    float sg = 0;
    float sb = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            sr = (0.393 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.769 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.189 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
            sg = (0.349 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.686 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.168 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
            sb = (0.272 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.534 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.131 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);

           image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(sr);
           image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(sg);
           image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(sb);
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
           if (image[i][j].rgbtRed > 255)
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtRed = 255;

           }

            if (image[i][j].rgbtGreen > 255)
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtGreen = 255;

           }

            if (image[i][j].rgbtBlue > 255)
           {
               image[i][j].rgbtBlue = 255;

           }

        }

    }

    return;

}`

Comment: `expected "25 22 17\n66 5...", not "25 22 17\n66 5..." - ERROR HERE`: This says you got what you expected.

Comment: but it still fails the check

Comment: Which check?  Is there a unit test you are running?  The code itself looks ok, though I would do the saturating to 2555 in the first nested loop instead of a second one - easier to follow.  Can you also post the typedef of `RGBTRIPLE` just in case the type is overflowing or something?  Also am not sure that you can have non-constant array sizes passed into the function, but I may be wrong there.

Comment: typedef struct
{
    BYTE  rgbtBlue;
    BYTE  rgbtGreen;
    BYTE  rgbtRed;
} __attribute__((__packed__))
RGBTRIPLE;                                                                                                                            This is fine here. I will try to do more research. What is expected is actually what I got but it still turns failed "expected "25 22 17\n66 5...", not "25 22 17\n66 5..." - ERROR HERE"

Comment: Any chance there is an error on where it is called?  Somehow giving it bad sizes and corrupting memory?  Or perhaps the output wants spaces or tabs or `\r\n` something?  Double check the assignment.  Maybe you fed the wrong sizes or array or something.

Comment: could be the spaces. I´ll take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before you call `round(s*)`, you need to check if `s* > 255`. If it is, then `image[i][j].rgbt* = 255;` if not, `image[i][j].rgbt* = round(s*);`, because the type of `image[i][j].rgbt*` is "Byte", so the maximum value is 255.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sr = (0.393 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.769 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.189 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
> sg = (0.349 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.686 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.168 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
> sb = (0.272 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.534 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.131 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
> ```

For this part you need to limit the pixel color to go past 255. You can make a function like this

```
int limit(int RGB)
{
    if (RGB > 255)
    {
        RGB = 255;
    }
    return RGB;
}
```

to limit it. You would also have to round the sepia colors using the round function